# Switch elements in priorityQueue

Tags: python, queue, tuples, priority-queue

I have this code:

```
q = PriorityQueue()
a = ((1, 1), 10, 0)
q.put(a)
newTuple = ((1,1), 8, 0)
res = any(newTuple[0] in item for item in q.queue) #res = true
```

Currently, I am checking if newTuple[0] (ie (1,1)) exists in any tuple in the priorityQueue. 
I'd like to alter the code so that it checks if newTuple[0] is in the queue, and if it indeed is (and is thus associated with some tuple 'a'), replaces this tuple 'a' in the queue with newTuple if newTuple[1] (ie, 8) is less than a[1] (ie, 10).

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're going to downvote me, can you please tell me how I can improve?

Comment: to my knowledge `PriorityQueue` is wrap around `heapq`, of course you could alter `q.queue`, but you need re-heapify it. why not use `heapq` directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to more flexibly access and modify value of the queue, maybe you can also try heapq instead of PriorityQueue

```
import heapq

heap = [((1, 1), 10, 0)]
heapq.heapify(heap)
for x in heap:
    print x,
```

you can search the heap because it's a list, and replace it directly. This is a good alternative.